# How get form vlaues in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How to get values from form. I have tried following code :

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AuthService} from "./AuthService";


interface Credentials {
  username: string,
  password: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  template: `
   <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(f.value)" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" ngControl="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" ngControl="password">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>    
  </form>
 `
 })

export class LoginComponent {

 credentials: Credentials;

 constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

 onLogin(credentials) {

console.log("username"+credentials.username,"password"+credentials.password);
this.auth.login(credentials);
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `name` attributes in your form, as well as binding with `ngModel`, with these Angular can track the input elements and associate it with an formcontrol.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" ngModel>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" ngModel>
```

Without these, your form object will just be an empty object.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WN0hTmqUYOKqEg2F6hN0?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you.Probably i wrong undestand for ngControl directive.

Answer (score 3):

You should Do it like this

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(f.value)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" ngModel>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" ngModel>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>    
</form>
```

And

```
onLogin(f){
    console.log("username :"+f.username,"password :"+f.password);
}
```